# gksudo replacement for gnome 3

Tags: sudo, gnome-shell, gnome-3, gksudo

`gksudo` doesn't support persistent sessions - normally the `sudo` command retains the privilege granted as a session which lasts 5 minutes or so. `gksudo` doesn't feature this, and requires the user to enter a password each time. While using gnome 3 (via ubuntu gnome), I have seen some programs which prompt the need for a password in a more modern, gnome-3 style, while having the behavior I described in `sudo` above. What is this program, or a program which has the features I require? Specifically - a GUI for `sudo` which retains the privileged session for some timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no replacement; Graphical applications are not designed to and should not be ran as a different user. If an application requires root privileges it should be designed as multiple processes where a small minimal process can be elevated.

You would use Polkit at that point to launch the new process as root though.

Answer (score 3):

Since gksudo and similar are now deprecated, pkexec might be an option if your system includes it.

So, instead of

```
sudo dolphin
```

Try

```
pkexec dolphin
```

You may have to configure the policy for dolphin to allow GUI usage as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203136/how-do-i-run-gui-applications-as-root-by-using-pkexec